# ORA-02289 последовательность не существует

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Добавил sequence в Oracle 11g r2, но код не видит ее почему-то

```
using (OracleConnection ConnectionToOracle = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LABA2.\"questions\" VALUES (autonum.nextval, :b)";
            cmd.Connection = ConnectionToOracle;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(":a", OracleType.Number).Value = a;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":b", OracleType.VarChar).Value = b;
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
            ConnectionToOracle.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Запись успешно добавлена. Ждите связи с менеджером");
```

Пробовал через сам Oracle, там ошибка с полем. У меня Number стоит на id, а что нужно я не знаю

Comment: А как вы создали последовательность? Добавте выражение прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Если попробовать воспроисвести задачу в вопросе, то можно убедится, что всё работает как ожидалось:

```
create table tab1 (id number);
Table TAB1 created.

create sequence seq1 increment by 1 maxvalue 50000 nocycle;
Sequence SEQ1 created.

insert into tab1 values (seq1.nextval);  
1 row inserted.
```

Поэтому, причина ошибки: последовательность с указанным именем не определена или не известна в схеме, в которой производится вставка в таблицу. Следует также учесть, что имя `sequence_name` и `"sequence_name"` это разные имена.

Подробне об доступности имён объектов в схемах в [оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561).